# Django show the progress of a script in real time

Tags: django, websocket

I launch a long script throught a web interface with django, I would like to notify the progress of the script in real time, the client will see in a popup everything the script is doing.

In the script when I make a print('parsing xml file...'), I would like the client to see it in a popup.

How could I do that please, because I only know ajax and this is not possible to do with ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know any ready solution, but I can give you some tips (no websocket required):

1. your script writes its progress somewhere (on the db, in a text file, ...)
2. your popup makes timed ajax calls and reads the progress (with some 'end-mark' in order to stop the process)